# What is the difference between objectivity and symmetry?

Tags: conservation-laws, symmetry, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain, solid-mechanics

I encounter this question when reading a paper about continuum mechanics ([Kumar and Parks, 2015, Proc.R.Soc.A](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rspa.2014.0567). refer to eq.3.1 and eq.3.3)

Speaking of the **objectivity** of strain energy density ${\psi}$, it reads like,

$$\psi=\hat\psi(F)=\hat\psi(QF)$$

where arbitrary ${Q\in SO_2}$ denotes a rigid-body rotation, and $F$ is the deformation gradient, which is a two-point tensor and should transform like a 1-order tensor.

As for the **symmetry** of ${\psi}$, it reads like,

$$\psi=\bar\psi(E)=\bar\psi(Q^TEQ)\quad \forall Q\in G \, ,$$

where $G$ denotes the material symmetry group, and $E$ is a kind of strain measure, which is a 2-order tensor.

- I am confused by these two equations because it seems to me that both objectivity and symmetry are expressed as rotation-transformation invariance of strain energy density $\psi$. But they don't feel the same, instinctively.
- Could somebody explain the difference between objectivity and symmetry and the corresponding mathematical expression?